# Select date in descending order

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with the below details

[image]

For view database details i tried with the query

```
SELECT * FROM itinv_log WHERE catname=:catname AND itemname=:itemname ORDER BY setdate DESC
```

It is showing result in the order of:

```
02-02-2016 stock_in added 
03-02-2016 stock_in added
04-02-2016 stock_in added
25-01-2016 stock_in added
26-01-2016 stock_in added
```

I want the result should be in the order of:

```
04-02-2016 stock_in added
03-02-2016 stock_in added
02-02-2016 stock_in added
26-01-2016 stock_in added
25-01-2016 stock_in added
```

If anyone knows the solution.Please help me out of this problem.

Comment: MySQL date format is `yyyy-mm-dd` so the order will be in this format. If you need another kind of order you need to make it by php for example

Comment: Data type for `setdate` is a string type, so you get an alphabetic order. You should not store dates in strings. change the column data type to DATE and you are done.

Comment: It is already in DATE format only.

Comment: This cannot be. If it were DATE already, you would not get your results in alphabetic order, but ordered by date. Or ... or you are changing the order in PHP somehow after retrieving the rows from the database.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner On a properly formatted date, it makes no difference to the ordering whether it's a string or a date data type.

Comment: Can we see the actual query?

Comment: in database date is storing like 2016-01-02 to show it in normal order i use php <?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['setdate'])); ?>.

Comment: @strawberry it is in date datatype only. actual query i specified in question

Comment: @KavyaShree No. You specified the pre-prepared query in the question.

Comment: I tried with Others answer also but it is not working in my code

Comment: @Strawberry: You are right; strings as 'yyyy-mm-dd' would be ordered correctly. And as the date is sometimes shown as dd-mm-yyyy and sometimes as yyyy-mm-dd in the request above, it is likely that the column *is* a date. So either we are shown a wrong query and it's really ordering by a formatted date string or the order is changed in PHP later.

Comment: @Kavya Shree: You are being asked to show your actual code, which is PHP, isn't it?

Comment: It is very big file.if i show entire code means u ll be confused thats why pasted corresponding code alone.

Comment: While insert i use datepicker and store datas in date format..and while display data from database i use phpcode <?php echo date("d-m-Y", strtotime($row['setdate'])); ?> for display in the order of day-month-year

Answer (score 0):

Use the `STR_TO_DATE` function to order it by actual date values rather than a numerical value.

```
SELECT * 
FROM itinv_log 
WHERE catname=:catname 
AND itemname=:itemname 
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(setdate , '%d/%m/%Y') DESC
```

Comment: If i tried like this means it is showing the error unexpected %

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '%' in /home/sunmace/public_html/testing/item_inv/item_inv.php on line 57 ..This is what i got when trying this syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can `CAST` the value to `date`

```
SELECT * FROM itinv_log WHERE catname=:catname 
AND itemname=:itemname ORDER BY CAST(setdate AS DATE) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `setdate` column is string type.
Better case - convert your `setdate` to [something more suitable for date](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/DATETIME.html), but if you can't do it, maybe you can use this field like:

```
SELECT *, STR_TO_DATE(setdate, '%m/%d/%Y') as formattedDate 
FROM itinv_log 
WHERE catname=:catname AND itemname=:itemname ORDER BY formattedDate DESC
```

Comment: I tried this @alexey im getting unexpected % error.

Comment: DATE_FORMAT(`setdate`, '%Y %M %d') AS formattedDate

Comment: %W means??Where i want to define this